# Componente não atualiza

Tags: vue.js, plotly

Estou criando um componente Vue de gráfico do Plotly. No carregamento inicial o componente é carregado com os valores iniciais corretos, mas quanto atualizado a propriedade do componente, ele não é atualizado.

Componente:

```js
<template>
    <div
    ref="plot1"
    id="plot1"
    ></div>
</template>

<script>
  import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js'

  export default {
    name: 'graph',
    props: ['plot_data'],
    data: function () {
      return {
        data_plot: this.plot_data,
        layout: { },
      }
    },
    methods: {

    },
    mounted () {
      Plotly.plot(this.$refs.plot1, this.data_plot, this.layout, { displayModeBar: false })
    },
  }

</script>
```

Página que insere o componente:

```html
<graph
              :plot_data="data_plot"
              :layout="layout"
              :display-mode-bar="false"
></graph>
```

```js
import graph from './component/Graph.vue'

...

data () {
      return {
      ....
        data_plot: [{ x: [3, 2, 1], y: [3, 2, 1], type: 'scatter' }],
      }
    },
    
      send_site: function () {
        console.log(this.$refs.tuple_ann.value)
        var data = new FormData()
        ....
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api_app/ann/', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
          .then((response) => {
            ....
            this.data_plot = [{ x: response.data.x, y: response.data.y, type: 'scatter' }]
          })
      },
```

A variável data_plot é atualizada corretamente após o request, mas o componente "graph" não é atualizado. O que poderia ser?
Obrigado.

Comment: E se você referenciar o plot_data direto? Sem setar no data_plot?

Comment: testei aqui e continua não atualizando

Comment: Os dados chegam normal do axios?

Comment: chegam sim. Acabei de resolver adicionando o atributo key="data_plot" no <graph>

Comment: Legal. Que bom que resolveu... eu ia dar outra dica, ja que deu certo, aproveite rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema adicionando o atributo key="data_plot" no .

```js
<graph
  :plot_data="data_plot"
  :key="data_plot"
  :layout="layout"
  :display-mode-bar="false"
></graph>
```